# Expand abbreviations from words in a string itself

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe column with expanded words and their abbreviated form in each row.
How could i replace abbreviations with their expanded form in the row.

for example - 
input df

`df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Words':['Chief Environmental Commitment Officer (CECO)',
'Advertising Director (Ad Director)',
'Digital Advertising Manager (Digital Ad Manager)','Postmaster Relief (PMR)']})`

output df

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Words':['Chief Environmental Commitment Officer (CECO)',
'Advertising Director (Ad Director)',
'Digital Advertising Manager (Digital Ad Manager)','Postmaster Relief (PMR)'],
                     'Output':['Chief Environmental Commitment Officer Chief Environmental Commitment Officer',
                               'Advertising Director Advertising Director',
                               'Digital Advertising Manager Digital Advertising Manager',
                               'Postmaster Relief Postmaster Relief']})
```

I don't want to create a dictionary of the abbreviations and then replace them, is there any other way, since i am a bit new to python

Comment: what is your desire output format?

Comment: output column must have strings format in each row or even list will work

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions. For example:

```
import re

def replaceAbb(words):
    words = re.sub(r'(\(CECO\))', 'Chief Environmental Commitment Officer', words)
    # repeat above line for all other abbrevations
    return words

# apply this function over the column in df
df_1['Output'] = df_1['Words'].apply(replaceAbb)
```

https://regexr.com/ is a good site to test/build regular expression in case you are confused.

Comment: but according to this i would need to create custom regex for each row

Comment: i needed to have something generic